# Is a Lisp program in both prog-mode and lisp-mode?

Tags: major-mode, prog-mode

Upon reading [`(emacs) Program Modes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Program-Modes.html):

> Entering a programming language mode runs the custom Lisp functions
>   specified in the hook variable `prog-mode-hook`, followed by those
>   specified in the mode's own mode hook (see Major Modes). For instance,
>   entering C mode runs the hooks `prog-mode-hook` and `c-mode-hook`. See
>   Hooks, for information about hooks.

Does it mean that C programming is running under `prog-mode` and `c-mode`?

Is `prog-mode` a universal mode for all the programs?

It additionally implies that `prog-mode` is a major mode like `c-mode`.

Nevertheless:

> Major modes are mutually exclusive; each buffer has one and only one major mode at any time.

(from [`(emacs) Modes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modes.html))

What does `prog-mode` do here, is it a minor mode but stated vastly in the major mode part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it mean that C programming is running under `prog-mode` and `c-mode`?

No, because, as you later quote:

> Major modes are mutually exclusive; each buffer has one and only one major mode at any time.

So your buffer can only be in one or the other.

> Is `prog-mode` a universal mode for all the programs?

No, it is a universal **parent** mode for all programming modes.

> It additionally implies that `prog-mode` is a major mode like `c-mode`.

Yes, `prog-mode` is a normal major mode derived from `fundamental-mode`. Similarly `c-mode` is a normal major mode derived from `prog-mode`. The difference is that `prog-mode` alone is quite bare, and is not intended to be enabled directly.

> What does `prog-mode` do here, is it a minor mode but stated vastly in the major mode part?

No, it is a normal major mode. It is provided as a convention for major mode authors to derive their modes from, and as a convenience for users to more easily customise all their programming modes.

For example, if a user wants to enable `show-trailing-whitespace` in all their programming modes, they may first define a hook like the following:

```el
(defun my-show-trailing-space ()
  "Enable `show-trailing-whitespace' in the current buffer."
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace t))
```

Instead of adding this function to the mode hook of every programming mode they use, like so:

```el
(mapc (lambda (hook)
        (add-hook hook #'my-show-trailing-space))
      '(c-mode-common-hook
        emacs-lisp-mode-hook
        perl-mode-hook
        prolog-mode-hook
        ...))
```

They can instead simply add it to the mode hook of the parent mode, i.e. `prog-mode-hook`:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-show-trailing-space)
```

As such, `prog-mode` provides common settings for all programming modes derived from it.

Comment: impressive explanation, ty.

Comment: You can find more details about derived modes and mode hooks in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105